# Convert html to pdf header with selectPDF

Tags: .net, pdf, html-to-pdf

I use selectPDF to convert a html page to a PDF document. For the body this is not problem. I can use convertUrl to convert to a PDFDocument.

But can I also do this for a PDFHeader? My header is a separate .html page.

Thanks in advance,
Jeroen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me while to find it, but there is an example on the site of SelectPDF how to do this.

http://selectpdf.com/demo/html-to-pdf-headers-and-footers.aspx

The documentation itself is not so clear about this.